# K-means Coding Implementation

Tags: matlab, k-means

I am looking for an implementation of k-means that will out where each row of data belongs too.

I have found other links like [Matlab:K-means clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373516/matlabk-means-clustering) 
But they do not help.

So I am looking for something like this. If my data is as follows

```
1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6
```

I would like to know that Row 1 Belongs to Cluster A and Row 2 Belongs to Cluster B and so on.

Does anyone know if Matlab can show me that, if so how? If not does anyone have a link to some code that would be able to do that?

Comment: actually the answers in the question you linked show how to get the cluster indices of each row.. You should also read the doc page of the [KMEANS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/kmeans.html) function

Comment: Have a look at my post at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859213/k-means-algorithm-with-arbitrary-distance-function-matlab-chebyshev-distance/45223789.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the kmeans command from [Statistics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/statistics) will do this. Here's an example using the Fisher Iris dataset that is supplied with the toolbox. `meas` is a 100x4 dataset of four anatomical variables (petal length, petal width, sepal length, sepal width) measured on 150 irises. The output variable, which I've here called `clusterIndex`, tells you which cluster each row of the dataset falls into, and can be used, for example, as a variable to color points in a plot.

```
>> load fisheriris
>> k = 3;
>> clusterIndex = kmeans(meas,3);
>> scatter(meas(:,1),meas(:,2),[],clusterIndex,'filled')
```

[image]