# K-Means Algorithm with Arbitrary Distance Function MATLAB (Chebyshev Distance)

Tags: matlab, k-means

Is there a way to set another distance in the K-means than those five implemented 
in the Matlab, for example the Chebyshev distance:

D=max(abs(xj-xi))

Thank you.

Best,

Pavlos

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any specific reason for using K-means, and can cope with Hierarchical Agglomerative Clustering, than you can use the [`clusterdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/clusterdata.html) function. It works also with chebyshev distance.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm

http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php

In addition, there is another concept of calculating distance between two points named "**City Block Distance**" which is something similar to the ABSOLUTE distance of two points. Example:

Distance, `d = |x2-x1| + |y2-y1|` OR 
          `d = |x1-x2| + |y1-y2|` (As the results are absolute, any form will do) 
Please check and try.

Comment: You tell him the exact opposite of what he wants to do. He wants L\inf and you tell him to use L1.

Answer (score 0):

The Chebyshev distance is equivalent to the infinity [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm). This should help you in searching in the Matlab documentation.

I read through the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/stats/kmeans.html) of K-means in Matlab and there is no way mentioned to expand the function with additional distance norms. So, you should probably implement it by yourself.

The other option would be to look for a mapping from Linf to L2 but this doesn't exist. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I second that hierarchical clustering may be more along the lines of what you want since you can specify the distance function easily.

However, if you really want to use k-means, you could create a distance matrix using any function you like and break down your distance matrix into a feature space using SVD. Then, perform k-means on the new feature space represented by the scores of the SVD.

I don't know that K-means would converge with other distance metrics.

Answer (score 0):

I created a MATLAB Code for very simple K-Means which accepts arbitrary Distance Function.

You can get the code on the [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/StackOverflow/Q9859213).

Here are the results for 3 different distance metrics:

[image]

[image]

[image]