# Passing Custom Distance Functions in K-Means

Tags: matlab, k-means

Is there a way of passing custom distance functions (e.g. jaccard distance) in MATLAB k-means
implementation?

jaccard distance function

```
D = pdist(X,'jaccard');
```

Comment: If you want to see simple implementation which can be used with any arbitrary distance function have a look at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859213/k-means-algorithm-with-arbitrary-distance-function-matlab-chebyshev-distance/45223789.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is break down your distance matrix into a feature space using SVD, then perform kmeans on the new feature space represented by the scores of the SVD. See Elements of Statistical Learning by Rob Tibshirani.

Or you can do k mediods which works with a distance matrix - as.dist() in R will convert a matrix to a dist object that you can then do K-mediods on.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/stats/kmeans.html), we learn that we can pass a `'distance'` option to `kmeans`:

> 'distance'
>
> Distance measure, in p-dimensional space. kmeans minimizes with
>   respect to this parameter. kmeans computes centroid clusters
>   differently for the different supported distance measures.
>
> 'sqEuclidean'
>
> Squared Euclidean distance (default). Each centroid is the mean of the
>   points in that cluster.
>
> 'cityblock'
>
> Sum of absolute differences, i.e., the L1 distance. Each centroid is
>   the component-wise median of the points in that cluster.
>
> 'cosine'
>
> One minus the cosine of the included angle between points (treated as
>   vectors). Each centroid is the mean of the points in that cluster,
>   after normalizing those points to unit Euclidean length.
>
> 'correlation'
>
> One minus the sample correlation between points (treated as sequences
>   of values). Each centroid is the component-wise mean of the points in
>   that cluster, after centering and normalizing those points to zero
>   mean and unit standard deviation.
>
> 'Hamming'
>
> Percentage of bits that differ (only suitable for binary data). Each
>   centroid is the component-wise median of points in that cluster.

So, for example:

```
[idx,ctrs] = kmeans(X,2, 'Distance','cityblock');
```

As for *custom* functions (i.e., user-implemented): AFAIK, this is not possible without hacking the relevant m-files.