# Best Way to Randomly Initialize Clusters in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, k-means

Say you have k clusters, and you have an array with n rows and 3 columns. Each row is a datapoint. What is the best (i.e., vectorized) way to randomly assign each row to a cluster.

Bonus points: commenting the code.

Comment: firstly, we will not write the code for you.

Comment: @Parag thanks for being super unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an n-length vector with integers 1 to k:

```
k = 4
n = length(examples)
cluster_assignments = randi(k,1,n)
```

and use the indexing to match up this n-length vector of cluster membership to the n examples you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you 2 options:

1. Random Initialization.
2. [K-Means++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B).

They are implemented in my [Stack Overflow Q22342015 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/StackOverflow/Q22342015).
The code includes K-Means implementation which accepts arbitrary Distance Function as in - [K-Means Algorithm with Arbitrary Distance Function MATLAB (Chebyshev Distance)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45223789/195787).

Result:

[image]